# What does mod_auth_passthrough do?

Tags: apache, apache-modules, mod-auth-passthrough

What does apache module mod_auth_passthrough is for exactly? It seems to be shipped with CPanel and sometimes is active. What exactly is it for and what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod_auth_passthrough is an Apache module that is used to allow other programs to use their
own authentication methods and passthrough the Apache webhost. (Pass-Through-Authentication)

cPanel uses it specifically to allow FrontPage® to use its own authentication system.

For more information on passthrough authentication see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms813076.aspx)

I can't find the source file of the module currently (mod_auth_passthrough.c), but reading that would provide a more detailed explanation of how it the module implements pass through authentication.